# Font pixelate when using matrix3d scale and backface-visibility

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, famo.us

**Code**: http://jsfiddle.net/quskwLdh/3/

I am using Famo.us and there is a usage of `matrix3d` to transform a `div`. It becomes problematic when I scale down some text and it started to get pixelated.

The code is below with 4 tests:

**First div (`style1`)**: Not using `matrix3d` but use `transform:scale(0.2)` instead. The font is smooth just fine.

**Second div (`style2`)**: Use `matrix3d` and `backface-visibility` (required in default Famo.us). It's smooth in Chrome but pixelate in Safari.

**Third div (`style3`)**: Update css with `matrix3d` on the fly dynamically (using `setTimeout`) but not use  `backface-visibility`. Again it's smooth in Chrome but pixelate in Safari.

**Fourth div (`style4`)**: Update css with `matrix3d` on the fly dynamically (using `setTimeout`) AND use  `backface-visibility`. This all screwed up in both Safari and Chrome as they're all pixelated.

**CHROME**

[image]

**SAFARI**

[image]

**HTML**

```
<div class="style1">
    TYPOGRAPHY
</div>

<div class="style2">
    TYPOGRAPHY
</div>

<div class="style3">
    TYPOGRAPHY
</div>

<div class="style4">
    TYPOGRAPHY
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    font-size:100px;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-family: georgia, serif;
}

.style1 {
    transform:scale(0.2);    
    -webkit-transform:scale(0.2);   
}

.style2 {
    transform:matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    -webkit-transform:matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}

.style3 {
}

.style4 {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-backface-visibility:hidden;
}
```

**JS**

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.style3').css('transform', 'matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)');    
    $('.style3').css('-webkit-transform', 'matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)');

    $('.style4').css('transform', 'matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)');
    $('.style4').css('-webkit-transform', 'matrix3d(0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1)');
}, 1000);
```

**Question**: Given that Famou.us needs to have `matrix3d` and `backface-visibility:hidden`, what's the workaround to have font smoothing in Chrome and Safari (I would not care about IE)?

I have done some research via [CSS3 scale() causes divs to become pixelated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11318676/css3-scale-causes-divs-to-become-pixelated) and [@font-face for custom fonts, fonts not smooth in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10627209/font-face-for-custom-fonts-fonts-not-smooth-in-chrome) so the usage of shadow, `-webkit-text-stroke: 0.3pt;` or `-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;` just don't work. Alternatively, maybe there is a way to modify/hack Famo.us itself?

Comment: I would set a callback after the the matrix transition to set the content to empty and put a new surface on top with smaller text. Hacky but I've done it before doesn't look bad if the scale duration isn't slow.